# jenkins.service failed because a timeout was exceeded

Tags: jenkins

[root@jenkins ~]# systemctl start jenkins
Job for jenkins.service failed because a timeout was exceeded. See "systemctl status jenkins.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

i installed jenkins and start then i get this error.

Comment: What does running `journalctl` give you? And what is the error that `systemctl status jenkins.service` shows?